How do I process text from the tty to obtain a txt with control characters applied to it?
I have a bashrc setup where I run a script command every time I open a session that writes to an output file as I write in the terminal.
The files that script produces contain all interactions with the tty (so arrow keys, delete key...).
I am trying to write a script that will obtain the last command I wrote along with it's ouptuts, but for this I need to convert the raw tty characters into readable text (so, for example, I remove all the bash color characters).
The problem I come up with, is that I can't just remove the control characters, I need to apply them somehow. I know this is possible to do without hard-coding what each control character does (after all, if I do cat terminal_output and hand copy the output I can simulate by hand what I want to achieve).
Example of the problem (I use my arrow keys to go back and add the first " character):
$ script -q -O out
$ echo "arrow keys"
arrow keys
$ exit

If I cat the file
$ cat out 
$ echo "arrow keys"
arrow keys
$ exit

If I just filter out the special characters:
$ cat out | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b 
$ echo 1@"ow keys"
arrow keys
$ exit

I want my tty to process the text with special characters and output the processed readable text so I can then use that instead.

With xterm you could convert output result to xhtml: xterm -e 'cat out;sleep .1;printf "\033[10i";read _', then html2text xterm.*.xhtml

I think as a precondition, you will have to set the terminal into raw mode (stty raw). Have a look at the stty man page, on how to restore the old state afterwards, in order to avoid unpleasant surprises. After this, you can read from your terminal (should be /dev/tty, but this may depend on the operating system).

"I know this is possible to do without hard-coding what each control character does" -- do you?  There is an important difference here between what you can do by hand and what you can do with a program: when output is written to an interactive device such as a tty, that device has the opportunity to process control characters, escape sequences, etc., possibly consuming them to produce special effects such a text coloring.  But if you redirect that same output to a file, instead, then you cut the terminal out of the loop.  [...]

[...] Yes, you can afterward take the captured output and send it to a terminal to get the wanted special-character processing, but that just brings you back to where you started: (formatted) output on the screen, not in a file.

You can run
TERM=dumb script -q -O out

and the output won't contain escape sequences, just simple control chars (e.g. ^G, ^H, ^M, etc.)
